# Can URLSearchParams get param case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, query-string

Can `URLSearchParams` somehow find param and not be case senstive?
For example in query I have `?someParam=paramValue`, so when I have
`URLSearchParams.get("someparam")` will it find `paramValue`?

Comment: 1. What have you tried so far? 2. You can always turn the url [to lower case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Comment: If you need that, you will probably have to build it yourself somehow. For this to be case-insensitive by default, would just make no sense – `?foo=1` and `?Foo=1` _are_ two different parameters to everyone else.

Comment: @Reyno - True, but that affects values as well as keys.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`URLSearchParams` keys are case sensitive. I don't see any suggestion in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) or [specification](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlsearchparams) to suggest a flag  controlling that behavior or an alternative method, etc.

It's quite straightfoward to convert all the names to lower case in a new `URLSearchParams` object, though:

```
const newParams = new URLSearchParams();
for (const [name, value] of params) {
    newParams.append(name.toLowerCase(), value);
}
```

Or if you want to condense it some:

```
const newParams = new URLSearchParams(
    Array.from(params, ([key, value]) => [key.toLowerCase(), value])
);
```

Live example:

```js
// The starting point from the question -- a URLSearchParams
// from "?someParam=paramValue"
const params = new URLSearchParams(
    "?someParam=paramValue"
);

// The thing from the question that doesn't work
console.log(params.get("someparam"));

// ---- Solution:

// Create a new URLSearchParams with all the keys lower case
const newParams = new URLSearchParams(
    Array.from(params, ([key, value]) => [key.toLowerCase(), value])
);

// Now using the lower case key works
console.log(newParams.get("someparam"));
```

Comment: That's a nice approach. I'd probably condense it to `const newParams = new URLSearchParams([...params].map(([key, value]) => [key.toLowerCase(), value]));`

Comment: also the search variable ("someparams" in this case) should be `.toLowerCase()` also, to handle caps in the search term.

Comment: @JoeyGough — Only if its an external input. The author can just write the string literal in lower case as they did in the question.

Comment: I have to use forEach... urlSearchParams.forEach(function (value, name) { newParams.append(name.toLowerCase(), decodeURIComponent(value)); });

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom function to get parameter value from location:

```
function getUrlParamValue(paramName){
    var params = new URL(location).searchParams;
    var keyName = Array.from(params.keys()).find(
        function(key){
            return key.toLowerCase() == paramName.toLowerCase();
        }
    );
    return params.get(keyName);
}
```

Example:
location = http://some.site.com/target?firstname=val

```
getUrlParamValue("FirstName") // returns val
```